# Optuna ConvergenceWarning on Lasso hyperparameter tuning study

Tags: python, lasso-regression, optuna

When fine tuning my Lasso model using Optuna, I get the following ConvergenceWarning..  Is it possible to increase nr. of iterations? I increased n_trials but it didn't help.

My code:

```
def objective(trial):

    _alpha = trial.suggest_float("alpha", 0.0001, 0.01)
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=_alpha, random_state=random_state)
    score = cross_val_score(lasso, X_train, y_train, cv=kf, scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error").mean()

    return score


optuna.logging.set_verbosity(0)

study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=300)
```

The error/warning:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:532:
> ConvergenceWarning:
>
> Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of
> iterations. Duality gap: 0.02194362081235468, tolerance:
> 0.01627441311545211

Answer (score 0):

According to the warning message, I think `Lasso` in the code is sklearn's [`Lasso`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html). So `n_trials` of optuna does not resolve the warning.

I think specifying a larger `max_iter` or `tol` arguments of [`Lasso`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) than the default values resolves the warning.